# End of string in c

Tags: c, string

I have to do a function to detect if the amount of '(' and ')' are equal in an expression. Since this is for university is a requirement to use simply linked lists with LIFO method.
Here is my code (it's not totally in english, if that's a problem I can translate it)

```
int balance (char * EXPRESION)

{
  int contador=0,flag=0,abre=0,cierra=0,devuelve=0;
  char fin='a',letra=0;
  nodo_t *H=NULL;


  printf ("HELLO\n");

  while (fin != '\0');
  {
    printf ("HELLOOOOOOOOO\n");
    fin = EXPRESION[contador];
    pila_push (&H,fin);
    contador++;
  }

  while (flag != 1)
  {
    flag = pila_pop (&H,&letra);

    if (flag != 1)
    {
      if (letra == '(')
      {
    abre++;
      }
      if (letra == ')')
      {
    cierra++;
      }
    }
  }

  if (abre==cierra)
  {
    devuelve=1;
  }
  else
  {
    devuelve=0;
  }

  return devuelve;
}
```

The function pila_push is just to add a node into the list and the function pila_pop is to remove the first node of the list and return the character read (this returns 1 when there is no node in the list)

Since the expression is a string I expect this to finish with '\0', but when I execute the program it hangs on the first while and never goes into it.

Many thanks in advance for your help.

This is how I input the expression to test the program:

```
int main (void)

{
  int aux=0;
  char expresion[10];

  printf ("Ingrese la expresion: ");
  __fpurge(stdin);
  scanf ("%s",expresion);

  aux = balance (expresion);

  if (aux == 1)
  {
    printf ("La expresion esta balanceada \n");
  }
  else
  {
    printf ("La expresion no esta balanceada \n");
  }

  return 0;
}
```

This is the output of the program with the two printfs added:

Ingrese la expresion: abc
HELLO
(it hangs here)

Comment: What is an example input for the expression?

Comment: Run it under a debugger, or add some printouts. What values are the loop control variables getting? Are you sure the expression is properly null-terminated?

Comment: I enter the expression manually. I just added the part of the program used to do that.

Comment: Just added 2 printfs to ensure it's not going into the first while. I attached the response of the program above.

Comment: Without seeing the definitions of `abin`, `pila_push`, and `pila_pop`, it's almost impossible to say where there is a problem.

Comment: It can not be said is investigating the match just count the number of brackets.

Comment: I cant believe I spent hours looking for the error and it was just this: while (fin != '\0');. Of course that ";" shouldnt be there